# Bibliography of works not cited does not print with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am using LaTeX with `reledmac` package for a critical edition. For the familiar notes I used customized citation keys. I didn't use the `\cite` command. That would complicate too much the code. I need to print the works cited in the familiar notes apparatus as SIGLA at the end of the introduction.

> 1 BDA: I, 3, cap. iiii, p. 86 || 2 BDA: I, 3, cap. iiii, p. 87 || 3 MolG. lib. IV, p. 148

Occasionally these notes might include quotations from the works cited:

> 4 Cf. RE, cap. XII, f. e verso et ss 156 || 5 FM f. 185r: ay por cuenta en Lisboa quinientas mugeres que venden hortaliza.

What I need is a way to sort the works cited, at the end of the introduction, or to be more specific, I need a list of Abbreviations (abbreviation + full bibliographic item) at the end of the introduction of the book, something like this:

> **BDA**    Barros, Joao, *Asia. Decadas*, Lisboa, 1935.
>
> **MolG**   Molezio, Giuseppe, Geographia Cl. Ptolemaei  [...], Venetiis, Apud Vincentium Valgrisium, 1572.

So these are not works cited. Yes, I have checked and I have tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563903/biblatex-works-cited-bibliography), and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306078/biblatex-doesnt-print-bibliography) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/how-to-split-bibliography-into-works-cited-and-works-not-cited). [One](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/563903/biblatex-works-cited-bibliography) of these solutions is what I need, but it does not work. Bibliography is not printed.
I have tried a table as well. But the table is so big it lies hidden at the page bottom.
Minimal work environment (the file using `reledmac` is not included in the main project so far, tough it is irrelevant for this question as the `main.tex` file, presently includes only the introduction):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,latin,portuges,]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Source Sans Pro}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,sorting=debug]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sigla.bib}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}
\nocite{*}



\usepackage{subfiles}

\begin{document}


\section*{Bibliografia}
\printbibliography

\begin{refsection}[sigla.bib]
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[title=Bibliography]
\end{refsection}

\end{document}
```

The `sigla.bib` is:

```
@Book{MorC,
  title     = {Las antiguedades de las ciudades de España},
  publisher = {en casa de Iuan Iñiguez de Lequerica},
  year      = {1575\noopsort{a}},
  author    = {Morales, Ambrosio de},
  address   = {Alcala de Henares},
  booktitle = {Las antiguedades de las ciudades de España},
}

@Book{MS,
  title     = {L. Marinei Siculi regii historiographi Opus de rebus Hispaniae memorabilibus},
  publisher = {per Michaelem de Eguia},
  year      = {1533\noopsort{a}},
  author    = {Marineo, Lucio},
  address   = {Impressum Compluti},
  edition   = {Modo castigatum atq[ue] Caesareae Maiestatis iussu in lucem aeditum.},
  keywords  = {Spain -- History -- Early works to 1800},
  language  = {lat},
  lccn      = {LC},
}

@Book{GrynaeusSimon1555Nora,
  title     = {Nouus orbis regionum ac insularum veteribus incognitarum},
  publisher = {Apud Io. Heruagium,},
  year      = {1555\noopsort{a}},
  author    = {Grynaeus, Simon and Herwagen, Johann and Huttich, Johann},
  address   = {Basileae},
  edition   = {Adiecta est huic postremae editioni Nauigatio Caroli Caesaris auspicio in Comitijs augustanis instituta..},
  keywords  = {Early printed books -- 16th century -- Facsimiles; Voyages and travels -- Early works to 1800; America -- Discovery and exploration -- Early works to 1800; America -- Early accounts to 1600},
  language  = {lat},
}

@Book{MyP,
  title     = {Episcopi gerundensis paralipomenon Hispaniae : libri decem antehac non excussi},
  publisher = {[Sancho e Sebastian de Nebrija]},
  year      = {1545},
  author    = {Margarit Y de Pau, Juan de, Cardenal, 1421-1484},
  address   = {Spain},
  language  = {lat},
}

@Book{NebR,
  title     = {Habes in hoc volumineamice lector. aelii Antonii Nebrissensis rerum a Fernando \et Elisabe Hispaniaru[m] foelicissimis Regibus gesta[rum] decades duas.},
  publisher = {[s.n.]},
  year      = {1545\noopsort{a}},
  author    = {Nebrija, Antonio de and Margarit y Pau, Juan de},
  address   = {Granada},
  
  keywords  = {Ferdinand V, King of Spain, 1452-1516; Isabella I, Queen of Spain, 1451-1504; Spain -- History -- Ferdinand and Isabella, 1479-1516; Castile (Spain) -- History -- Early works to 1800; Navarre (Kingdom) -- History -- Early works to 1800; Spain -- History -- To 711; Spain -- History -- 711-1516},
  language  = {lat},
}

@Book{NebD,
  title     = {Dictionarium oppidorum, civitatum, montium, fontium, fluviorum, lacuum, promontoriorum, portuum, sinuum, insularum et locorum memorabilium , in ordinem alphabeti digestorum},
  publisher = {Venundatur Parrhisiis a Reginaldo Chaudiere},
  year      = {1522\noopsort{a}},
  author    = {Nebrija, Antonio de},
  language  = {lat},
  url       = {http://ark.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k72672d},
}

@Book{MolG,
  title     = {Geographia Cl. Ptolemaei Alexandrini. Olim a Bilibaldo Pirckheimherio translata, at nunc multis codicibus graecis collata ... redacta a Iosepho Moletio Mathematico.},
  publisher = {apud Vincentvm Valgrisivm, MDLXII},
  year      = {1562\noopsort{a}},
  author    = {Ptolemy, Active 2nd Century},
  address   = {Italy},
  language  = {lat},
}

@Book{LA,
  title     = {Lectionum Antiquarum libri XXX},
  publisher = {per Ambrosium et Aurelium Frobenios fratres},
  year      = {1566\noopsort{a}},
  author    = {Richieri, Ludovico (1469-1525)},
  address   = {Basileae},
}

@Misc{IA,
  title     = {Pomponius Mela. Julius Solinus. Itinerarium Antonini Aug. Vibius Sequester. P. Victor de regionibus urbis Romae. Dionysius Afer de Situ orbis Prisciano interprete},
  year      = {1518\noopsort{a}},
  address   = {Venetiis},
  chapter   = {Itinerarium Antonini Augusti},
  publisher = {in aedibus Aldi et Andreae soceri},
}

@Book{GZ,
  title     = {Los XL libros d’el compendio historial de las chronicas y universal historia de todos los reynos de España},
  publisher = {por Christophoro Plantino},
  year      = {1571\noopsort{a}},
  author    = {Garibay y Zamalloa, Esteban de},
  address   = {en Anueres},
}

@Book{GTur,
  title     = {Turcicarum rerum commentarius [...], Parisiis, Ex officina Roberti Stephani, 1539},
  publisher = {Parisiis},
  year      = {1539\noopsort{a}},
  author    = {Giovio, Paolo},
  address   = {ex officina Roberti Stephani},
}

@Book{FOCron,
  title     = {Los çinco libros primeros de la Cronica general de España.},
  publisher = {por Guillermo de Millis},
  year      = {1553\noopsort{a}},
  author    = {Ocampo, Florian de},
  address   = {Medina del Campo},
}

@Book{FNL,
  title     = {Novum lexicon geographicum},
  publisher = {apud Franciscum Muguet},
  year      = {1670\noopsort{a}},
  author    = {Ferrari, Filippo},
  address   = {Parisiis},
}

@Book{PachecoPereiraDuarte1988Edso,
  title     = {Esmeraldo de situ orbis},
  publisher = {Academia Portuguesa da História},
  year      = {1988\noopsort{a}},
  author    = {Pacheco Pereira, Duarte and Peres, Damião},
  address   = {Lisboa},
  edition   = {3a ed. / introdução e anotações históricas pelo académico de número Damião Peres},
  keywords  = {Discoveries in geography -- Portuguese; Africa -- Discovery and exploration},
  language  = {por},
}

@Book{DPP,
  title     = {Esmeraldo de situ orbis},
  publisher = {Printed for the Hakluyt society},
  year      = {1937\noopsort{a}},
  author    = {Pacheco Pereira, Duarte and Kimble, George H. T},
  series    = {Works issued by the Hakluyt Society ; 2nd ser., no. 79},
  address   = {London},
  keywords  = {Discoveries in geography -- Portuguese; Africa -- Discovery and exploration},
  language  = {eng},
}

@Book{DP,
  title     = {Dionysii Afri de situ orbis: siue geographia, Prisciano, aut F. Rhēnio interprete lib. unicus. I. Camertis in eundem commentariolum.},
  publisher = {in aedibus Hieronymi Vietoris, et Ioannis Singrenii},
  year      = {1512\noopsort{a}},
  author    = {Dionysius and Camers, Joannes},
  address   = {Viennae Pannon},
  booktitle = {Dionysii Afri de situ orbis: siue geographia, Prisciano, aut F. Rhennio interprete lib. unicus. I. Camertis in eundem commentariolum},
}

@Book{RAnt,
  title     = {As antiguidades de Lusitânia},
  publisher = {Fundação Calouste Gulbenkian},
  year      = {2009\noopsort{a}},
  author    = {Resende, André de and Fernandes, Raul Miguel Rosado},
  series    = {Portugalliae Monumenta Neolatina ; 3},
  address   = {Lisboa},
  isbn      = {9789898074805},
  keywords  = {Names, Geographical -- Portugal; Portuguese language -- Etymology -- Names; Portugal -- History -- To 1385; Portugal -- Antiquities},
  language  = {por;lat},
}

@Book{HEx,
  title     = {Examen critique de la géographie du nouveau continent et des progrès de l'astronomie nautique aux quinzième et seizième siècles},
  publisher = {Librairie de Gide},
  year      = {1836\noopsort{a}},
  author    = {Humboldt, Alexander von},
  address   = {Paris},
}

@Book{HB,
  title     = {A Glossary of Colloquial Anglo-Indian Words and Phrases, and of Kindred Terms, Etymological, Historical, Geographical and discursive},
  publisher = {London},
  year      = {1903\noopsort{a}},
  author    = {Yule, Henry and A. C. Burnell A. C. and Crook, William and Hobson-Jobson},
  address   = {John Murray},
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but if you type your citations manually and never use `\cite` (or a related command), `biblatex` does not know which sources were actually cited in your document. If I try to run your code, I get several warnings and errors from Biber, I also get errors about `\noopsort` and `\et` being undefined. If I define the undefined commands I get two bibliography lists from your code.

Comment: Indeed the \noopsort was an attempt to print the bibliography without the two digits from the year in the key (the default for alpha style). The \et is a remain from an attempt to circumvent what I thought it were the constraints of Bibtex when dealing with Unicode and special Latex characters. Could you please provide an example of the cleaned code that outputs two lists?

Comment: I literally just added `\newcommand*{\noopsort}[1]{#1}\newcommand*{\et}{\&}` and ignored all the error messages from Biber. If your editor runs Biber for you and stops processing if Biber reports an error, you may have to fix the `author` field of `MyP` first: `author = {Margarit Y de Pau, Juan de, Cardenal, 1421-1484},` will not be parsed correctly. The `author` field should not contain dates of birth or death. By default you can only have family and given names as well as a family name prefix and a suffix like "Jr.".

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, the code you provided works. The only problem that remains is the key which Biber keeps printing according to its own internal commands and not the cite key I gave it. Like: [Ric6a] Ludovico  Richieri. Lectionum Antiquarum libri XXX. Basileae: per Ambrosium et Aurelium Frobenios fratres, 1566a. Instead of LA which I introduced  in the code: @Book{LA,  title

Comment: The documentation mentions a sortkey field which "if defined,
it serves as the master sort key". But I have inserted a field in some of the entries (sortkey= {LA}) but it does not have any effect.

Comment: You do not only want the sorting to change, you also want to fix the output. You can use `shorthand = {LA},` for that.

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I needed to print an Abbreviations list.

Answer (score 1):

Biber is unhappy about the `\noopsort` commands in the `year` field. They are not needed and will mess up sorting, so should be removed.

Biber also throws an error about the name format of the `author` in `MyP`

```
author = {Margarit Y de Pau, Juan de, Cardenal, 1421-1484},
```

contains too many commas and will not be parsed correctly. It is unusual to give the year of birth and death in the name field and even if there were no error, this would result in possibly very odd output.

---

On the LaTeX side the MWE would not compile because `\noopsort` and `\et` were not defined.

Since `\noopsort` should be removed anyway, you shouldn't have to define it, but

```
\newcommand*{\noopsort}[1]{}
\newcommand*{\et}{\&}
```

would probably be a sensible definition.

---

With all these issues fixed the MWE produces two identical bibliographies.

If you want to force a particular citation label, you can use the field `shorthand`. That usually overrides any automatically computed label. For example

```
@Book{MorC,
  shorthand = {MorC},
  title     = {Las antiguedades de las ciudades de España},
  publisher = {en casa de Iuan Iñiguez de Lequerica},
  year      = {1575},
  author    = {Morales, Ambrosio de},
  address   = {Alcala de Henares},
}
```

would show as

> MorC

---

That all said `biblatex` usually works best if you generate your citations with `biblatex` and not manually.

Comment: I had already removed the \noopsort and the dates from the name Margarit y Pau (the bibtex reference came from the Cambridge University Library Catalogue or from the SOLO of Oxford). I intend to use the \cite command in the introduction and in the translation. In the apparatus of the critical text, I will see later. At least I will give it a try.

Comment: Biblatex works fine in the critical apparatus. Output as desired.